# Cómo cambiar el nombre de la clase de un <li> o <label> en asp.net con c#

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, css3, webforms

tengo el siguiente Step Progress bar, desarrollado con html y CSS

```css
/* contain me: screen size*/
.screen {
    width: 80vw; /* 80% of screen width */
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 150px;
}

/* give me full width of my container */
.progress-container {
    width: 100%;
}

/* call CSS counter */
.progressbar {
    counter-reset: stepCount;
}

    /*  Set content area under circle */
    .progressbar li {
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        width: 33.33333333333333333333333%; /* 1/3 of 100% - would change on number of li */
        position: relative;
    }

        /* Create the circle, function for the number set, circle style,
use line height to vertically align numvber in center, height and line-height should be same */
        .progressbar li:before {
            counter-increment: stepCount;
            content: counter(stepCount);
            width: 65px;
            height: 65px;
            line-height: 65px;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
            background: lightblue;
            color: white;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-radius: 100px;
        }

        /* Connect circles w/ Background color, height, 
position-left is half of Li width, 
z-index pushes line behind circle*/
        .progressbar li:after {
            content: ' ';
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 5px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            top: 30px;
            left: -50%;
            z-index: -1;
        }


        /* Now we need to remove the extra line in front, select 1st li, and remove content to clear the front line */
        .progressbar li:first-child:after {
            content: none;
        }

        .progressbar li.active {
        }

            .progressbar li.active:before {
                background-color: dodgerblue;
            }

            .progressbar li.active:after {
                background-color: dodgerblue;
            }

.box {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="screen container align-content-center">
            <div class="progress-container">
                <ul class="progressbar">
                    <li class="active" id="box1">
                        <div class="box">
                            <h4><span>En gestión
                            </span></h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscinadipiscing elit feugiat eu blandit, m.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="active">
                        <div class="box">
                            <h4>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txtDerivada"></asp:Label>

                            </h4>


                            <p>eque conubia montes placeraro viverra praesent magna odio et enim ridiculus bibendum.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="" id="box3">
                        <div class="box">
                            <h4><span>Terminada</span></h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conseero viverra praesent magna odio et enim ridiculus bibendum.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Donde el `<li class="">` con la clase "active" se muestra de color azul, es por ello que quería saber si es posible agregar o cambiar el classname del li para dejarlo como activo a través de c# o quizás con JS.

la idea es dejarlo así `<li class="active">`

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Si estas trabajando con `asp.net` puedes acceder a un elemento html poniendo el `runat=server`

```
 <li class="active" id="box1" runat="server">
```

de esta forma desde un evento en el codigo de la pagina podrias hacer

```
box1.Attributes["class"] = "inactive";
```

Al poner el `runat server` conviertes el `tag html` en un

[07 - HTML Server Controls](https://www.wideskills.com/aspnet/html-server-controls)

por eso puedes accederlo desde codigo por su `id`

Comment: Maestro Tuttini probraré tu respuesta y te respondo

Comment: Muchas gracias maestro, sirvió perfecto